# Changing margin used \addtolength with a document class "Book" applied only to header

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry, textwidth

I'm using a documentclass "book" (`\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}`) and I want to increase the margin to be able to reduce the text width.

I've tried geometry but when using `\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2cm}` the command only change the headers of the pages (cf. image).

Any recommendation ?

Thanks for the support
Best
Jerome

[image: Textwidth changed for header not text]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There are more parameters that must be changed. Use the `geometry` package; it will properly change all the necessary parameters.